# Which source/tag should be used to download Odoo 12 community for Synology/Docker

Tags: docker, odoo, synology

Good Day:

I have been trying to create an Odoo 12 community version container on Docker in Synology DSM. Which source/tag should I use for this purpose?

The following source is the one I have been working with directly from Synology Docker:

https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/ 
(Tag: Latest)

The only thing I have been able to do is creating a container for Odoo 12 enterprise, but not for Odoo 12 community.

Please advise.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Odoo docker version is currently from date 2018-10-08 and it had a bug that showed incorrectly Enterprise version in Settings page also in Community version. So the good news is that you are in fact already running Community version. The bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/360212f2064e8bd72a3689f1e0104bfb73521f2a).

The more complicated question is what version of docker image should you run. The official Odoo docker image (library/odoo or _/odoo or just odoo) does not get updated very frequently. It is not updated to fix issues. I would not recommend it for any other use than testing.

You can use other images that are updated more frequently and have static tags, e.g. I maintain an image with nightly Odoo builds. It is named **veivaa/odoo**. You can use a specific version of Odoo nightly build with tag version-date, e.g. veivaa/odoo:12.0-20181106. The nightly image can be found in Docker store at https://store.docker.com/community/images/veivaa/odoo. This version is updated on ”best effort” bases.

You find more information on [running Odoo in Docker](https://unkkuri.com/blog/unkkuri-blog-1/post/odoo-12-in-docker-container-25) in my blog.

It is also not best practice with Docker to use the latest tag in production use or if you need to be able to keep the container stable. This is because you would get a different version depending on when you pull the image. Best practice is to either use a stable nonchanging tag, or build your own Dockerfile and image in own container registry.

Comment: Thank you Veikko. I will check this out and give feedback on this post.

Comment: Thank you Veikko. This worked =). Question: If I choose the latest build (2018114 at the moment) and not LATEST, will it still get updated automatically?   Also, if I understand correctly from your blog, I need to make another container for add-ons (making it 3 in total / Postgres, Odoo and Odoo Add-On)? Best Regards.

Comment: Additionally, do you recommend creating this containers through terminal with ssh. Until now I have been using the docker GUI, but I also have noticed the difficulties regarding using addons (given that Im unable to reach configuration folders within the SYNOLOGY SDM. Could I download (lets say the community source from ODOO webpage) and install it in my Synology Docker (SDM DOCKER APP or SSH Terminal). Or could I use your registry address (SDM DOCKER APP or SSH Terminal). Im planning to implement this as a business solution (but with the community version).

Comment: The daily tags do not get updates. Idea with static tagging is to be able to recreate the same environment. Updates should be done by creating a new container with newer tag. For this you need to have all data outside the container. All data meaning both filestore and addons. In my blog I use Docker volumes for this. You do not need a separate container for data.